# Need help migrating database from development to test using Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, testing, rails-migrations

Similar questions has been asked a lot. But, I think my situation is a bit different. I pulled  a db from Heroku (I use sqlite3 in prod) to my local machine (uses PostgreSQL ). The prod db didn't have any data at that time.

After that time I haven't done any db migrations to test. Now I have a couple of fields in my dev db. However, when I go to test console to see what I have (referring a User table) User.count returns 0, but returns 2 users in dev.

So I did rake `db:migrate RAILS_ENV=test` there was neither an error message nor a success message. I thought it was success and checked the test db if it has those 2 users and still nothing. Then I tried `bundle exec rake db:test:prepare`. This was the output

```
**You have 4 pending migrations:

  20120415210441 CreateUsers

  20120418064930 AddIndexToUsersEmail

  20120419034627 AddPasswordDigestToUsers

  20120504031144 AddRememberTokenToUsers

Run `rake db:migrate` to update your database then try again.**
```

What is the solution?

**EDIT:**
FYI: I am using windows
I also run **rake db:migrate**  and I got this error.

```
$ rake db:migrate
==  CreateUsers: migrating ====================================================
-- create_table(:users)
rake aborted!
An error has occurred, this and all later migrations canceled:

SQLite3::SQLException: table "users" already exists: CREATE TABLE "users" ("id"
INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT NOT NULL, "name" varchar(255), "email" varcha
(255), "created_at" datetime NOT NULL, "updated_at" datetime NOT NULL)

Tasks: TOP => db:migrate
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The error message indicates that your dev and test migrations are out of sync.

First run migrate on dev.  This will update dev with all your recent migrations.

```
rake db:migrate
```

Then run db:test:prepare.  This will make the test database the same schema as dev.

```
rake db:test:prepare
```

Now, understand that db:test:prepare makes test have the same schema as dev, but with no records.  To populate records in test, implement fixtures or factories (see the factory-girl gem).  Factories are generally called in your test to create records for that test.

Comment: Thank you for your response. When I run "rake db:migrate" below is what I got (I updated my question if you want to see in a neat format)
   
$ rake db:migrate
==  CreateUsers: migrating ====================================================
-- create_table(:users)
rake aborted!
An error has occurred, this and all later migrations canceled:

SQLite3::SQLException: table "users" already exists: CREATE TABLE "users" ("id"
INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT NOT NULL, "name" varchar(255), "email" varcha
(255), "created_at" datetime NOT NULL, "updated_at" datetime NOT NULL)

Comment: I forgot to ask one thing. How do you copy the values(all the rows  associated with each table) from your dev to test? I think rake db:migrate:prepare won't do that. Right?

Comment: I don't.  In fact db:test:prepare deletes all the records in the database.  Instead, I populate the records I need from calling factories or active record in my tests and fixtures.

Answer (score 1):

That's another question and another answer.

You should drop the table and re-run the migrations.

If you don't know how to drop a table in SQLite, then

1. comment out the create_table method call in the 20120415210441_CreateUsers.rb.
2. Run > rake db:migrate VERSION=20120415210441
3. Run > rake db:migrate VERSION=???  where ??? is the version of the migration prior to CreateUsers.
4. Uncomment the code in 20120415210441_CreateUsers.rb
5. Run > rake db:migrate